# Render nested list like a tree

Tags: html, css

How would I make the vertical border in this stop at the last element?

It can be CSS3/modern browser compatible only. But needs to work on various backgrounds (i.e. be transparent).

http://jsfiddle.net/ShgD6/

From this:

[image: Unwanted list]

To this:

[image: Wanted list]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this via modifications to the css in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YYdwc/2/

Comment: It's generally a good idea to provide some more information than just a link. You should include in your answer the modifications you made to the original code to make it work, and why you did what you did so people can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the last list item by using the CSS `:last-child` pseudo-class like this:

```
ul li:last-child {
    height: 0.7em;
}
```

Settings its height to 0.7em seemed to work for me, chopping off the tail on the left border. I added a few more nested groups in my fiddle to show it'll work even when the content changes and more nested groups are added.

http://jsfiddle.net/wdages/sC5pc/3/