# Using CSS, how can I join list elements to the previous one rather than the last entry in a nested list?

Tags: html, css

I have an unodered list with nested unordered lists.  I have managed to get list elements to look like they are connected to the one before, but when I get to a nested UL it doesn't join up.  Take a look at the picture to see what I mean.

Essentially, it looks like this from an HTML perspective:

```css
ul{
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;  
}

/* ***** LINES BETWEEN CARDS ***** */
ul.peoplelist li {
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 0; }

ul.peoplelist li:before {
    /* lines */
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px; 
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 96px;
    width: 30px;
    top: -56px;
}
/* Just to shorten the top bar a little */
ul.peoplelist li:first-child:before {
    top: -16px;
   height: 60px;
}





/* ***** CARDS ***** */

/* Design from here: http://codepen.io/MattiaAstorino/pen/VYWxXy */
button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.card {
  will-change: transform;
  /*margin: 8px;*/
  margin: 16px;
  /*padding: 8px 8px;*/
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00abc1;
   color: #ffffff;
  height: 35%;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
}
.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card__image {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.card__image:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  bottom: 0;
}
.card__title {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-weight: 200;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.card__subtitle {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 80px;
  right: 0;
  top:30px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.card__action-bar {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.card--small {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
}
.card--small .card__image {
  border-radius: 1px 0 0 1px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80px;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 136px;
}
.card--small .card__image:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.card--small .card__title {
  left: 80px;
  top: 8px;
}
.card--small .card__subtitle {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 80px;
}
.card--small .card__teamtitle {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 80px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.card--small .card__action-bar {
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="peoplecards">
    <ul id="topDog" style="display: block;">
        <li>
            <div class="card card--small">
                <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <ul class="peoplelist" id="peoplelist" style="display: block;">
            <li>
                <div class="card card--small">
                    <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                    <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                    <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="card card--small">
                    <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                    <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                    <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="card card--small">
                    <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                    <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                    <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="card card--small">
                    <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                    <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                    <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card card--small">
                            <div style="background-image: url(blank.jpg)" class="card__image"></div>
                            <h2 class="card__title">Person Name</h2><span class="card__subtitle">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="card__action-bar"><span class="card__teamtitle">Team Title</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

I'll try and put it into a jsfiddle or something too.
*Update - [here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dparkinson/fc2s6wcb/) *

Thanks for any feedback anyone can provide.

Comment: We need to see the CSS you are using. Please add it.

Comment: Sure... I'm just trying to paste it into a jsfiddle now...

Comment: Take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361858/render-nested-list-like-a-tree

Comment: Just added the jsfiddle for it...

Comment: Your code should be in your post also.

Comment: Could do, but it's quite long?

Comment: Just the parts needed to replicate your issue. i.e. you probably don't need to include every `li` and `ul` you have in the JSFiddle, just a couple at each level. This way, if the JSFiddle gets deleted, the question and answer will still have relevance.

Comment: Added the code to the question as requested

Comment: Hi Darren, try putting 2nd level UL inside LI. Validating your markups might help.  (</li> 
        <ul class="peoplelist" id="peoplelist" style="display: block;">)

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that error.  On fixing it, it doesn't actually answer the question though unfortunately.

Comment: no guts to post an answer but i made it easy by targetting the 2nd UL ...  .. see https://jsfiddle.net/szz9qk9d/  if this is good with you, you'll be able to self answer your question.